# Probability space for gambling game with two urnes

Tags: probability-theory

> Assume you participate in the following game: You and the game master each receive one urn with $n$ balls, which are numbered consecutively from $1$ to $n$. You and the game master grab a ball randomly and independent from each other from your urn. Then, the game master pays you the distance $X$ of the numbers on the balls that you just grabbed. Your stake is $n/3$ euros.
>
> Determine a probability space for this kind of game.

First, I would define $\Omega$ to be the set of all possible combinations of balls / numbers that were grabbed, so

$$\Omega := \{(1, 1), (1, 2), ..., (2, 1), ..., (n, n)\}.$$

Then, it might be useful to define the $\sigma$-algebra as the power set of $\Omega$ since, in the end, we are interested in our possible gain / loss, and there will be specific subsets of $\Omega$ that guarantee us such a gain / loss.

Besides that, I choose my probability measure $P$ to be a hypergeometric distribution, because we want to know how likely it is to have certain combinations of balls in order to make sure that we receive a win.

Does this make sense so far?

Comment: Just to be clear: by "distance $X$ of the numbers on the balls" do you mean the absolute value of the difference of the two numbers?

Comment: I believe that this is meant, yes.

Comment: On the probability space the measure is $\frac1{n^2}$ for every atom. Then, it is another question what $X$'s distribution is.